# Is there a way to do multiple replace calls inside a query

Tags: sql, replace

I"ve got a query that looks like:

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(address, ' CA', '')) FROM Tbl
```

I now need to do multiple replaces on a filed before calculating it's length.

ie, I need to do something like:

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(address, ' CA', '') AND REPLACE(address, ' CA', '')) FROM Tbl
```

which is obviously incorrect SQL.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using MS-SQL 2008 if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! You just have to nest them

```
select
replace(
    replace(address,' CA','')
, '   CA','') as blerg
from TBl
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to nest the function calls like so:

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(address, ' CA', ''), ' NY', '')) FROM Tbl
```

The above query will get you the length of the string after replacing " CA" and " NY" with "".  I swapped out your second " CA" with " NY" because replacing " CA" with "" twice is redundant.